# Would a $50\: \mathrm{Hz}$ spinning magnetic plate in front of a human generate harmful current?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current, biophysics, induction

We know that spinning magnetic plate will generate current inside any wire. so if we stand before 50Hz spinning magnetic plate, then, does that 50Hz spinning magnetic plate in front of us (human body ) generate current inside human body which will cause harm to body?

By considering the fact, human body is not bad conductor of electricity.

Comment: Unless the plate is a Magnetar you'll be fine.  Your body doesn't have coils of wire so any tiny amount of material that would induct would be too inefficient to cause any harm.  Heck, it's be to inefficient for you to even notice.

Comment: Change $50\,\mathrm{Hz}$ to $2.45\,\mathrm{GHz}$ and you might start to notice some effects. So will your neighbours.